# Is there a better way of validating a non model field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a form field in ROR 4 app called as 'measure'. It is not a database column, but its values will help model create child entries of its own via acts_as_tree : https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree

I have to throw a validation when 'measure' is invalid. So I have created a virtual attribute known as measure and check for its validations only on a certain condition.

```
model someModel 
attr_accessor :measure
 validates_presence_of :measure, :if => condition?
```

Problem is when I am saving the code, I am thrown a validation which is fine. I am also thrown the same validation when I am trying to update the record in some other method of the model. The only way to surpass that is by writing this code:

```
   # I do not want to do this, is there a better way?
   self.measure = "someRandomvalue" 
   self.save
```

I am making this as virtual attribute only for throwing validations. Is there a better way of throwing validations? The form has other validations, I do not want the error for this validations to be shown differently just because it is not an attribute.

I want it to validated only when active record is saved via create and update action of the controller and not when it is being updated by some random method of model.

Comment: You can achieve this by doing : `validates :measure, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |resource| resource.changes[:measure].present? && your_other_condition }` (Rails 3 & 4 syntax, use `validates_presence_of` if using Rails 2)

Comment: So does the validation only need to happen once on creation or does it need to happen whenever the values of measure changes?

Comment: You're doing the right thing, you apply validation to non-persisted attributes the same as you do to persisted attributes. But I'm confused, you say you want to validate the presence, but then you complain that it IS validating the presence, that it's raising when you save with a blank value. Isn't that exactly what you told it to do and want it to do, though?  I don't think the issue is whether it's a db column or not, the issue is that you need to be clear about when/how you want it validated, and implement that -- the same way you would for a db column.

Comment: thank you, I want it to validated only when active record is saved via create and update action of the controller and not when it is being updated by some random method of model .

Answer (score 0):

I have seen other developers in my team doing similar thing and was always curious about one thing - "What are you trying to achieve doing things the way you are doing?". You see, I am not sure if validators should be used for values that will not be serialized.

Anyways, you may try using `format` validator instead of `presence`, which worked in my team's case:

```
# Rails 3/4
validates :measure, format: { with: /^.+$/, allow_nil: true }

# Rails 2
validates_format_of :measure, :with => /^.+$/, :allow_nil => true
```

You may also try using `allow_blank` instead of `allow_nil`.

I would rather create a custom validator along the lines of `validates_accessor_of` for values that I know will never be serialized.

HTH